# Swift -Change a Struct value inside Array that is the value of a Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

In the code below, how can I change Jack's drink from "Lemonade" to "Soda" inside the `groupingDict`.

```
struct User {
    var name: String?
    var drink: String?
}

let u1 = User(name: "Jack", drink: "Lemonade")
let u2 = User(name: "Jill", drink: "Iced Tea")

let list = [u1, u2]

var groupingDict = Dictionary(grouping: list, by: { $0.name })

print("groupingDict-original: ", groupingDict)

for (index, dict) in groupingDict.enumerated() {

    if dict.key == "Jack" {

    }
}

print("groupingDict-changed: ", groupingDict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Jack's group, go through each object using `reduce(into:)` and create a copy of the object and set the drink to "Soda" if it is "Lemonade"

```
if let jacksGroup = groupingDict["Jack"] {
    let modified = jacksGroup.reduce(into: []) {
        $0.append($1.drink == "Lemonade" ? User(name: $1.name, drink: "Soda") : $1)
    }

    groupingDict["Jack"] = modified
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it. You can use `firstIndex(where: { }` to get the index of the item, change the property, create a copy tf the item then assign to the dictionary value:

```
for (_, dict) in groupingDict.enumerated() {
    
    if dict.key == "Jack" {

        if var arr = groupingDict["Jack"] {

            if let indexOfItem = arr.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Jack" }) {

                arr[indexOfItem].drink = "Soda"
                
                let copyOfItem = arr[indexOfItem]
                
                groupingDict["Jack"] = [copyOfItem]
            }
        }
    }
}
```